# Populate Combobox with data from SQlite databases using Tkinter and Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

**Goal**: Populate Combobox with data from SQlite database
I have this function

```
def inptcm():
    """Set values in the Combobox named cmbo"""
    dcon = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    pcur = dcon.cursor()
    pcur.execute('SELECT appname FROM mytable')
    data = []
    for row in pcur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    return data
```

I am using the above function to populate this Combobox below

```
cmbo = ttk.Combobox(fnb2, values=inptcm)
cmbo.place(x=10, y=50)
```

The values from the query should be "Test1", "Test2" the data type for the column "appname" is text in the SQlite table

But the results I get from the above  in my combobox is:

[image]

Not too sure what I am missing

Comment: You need the result of `inptcm()`, so it is `values=inptcm()`.

Comment: That was the problem..... attention  to detail.. - Thank you !